# Position Selenium Firefox driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, gnome

I'm trying to start up several Selenium Firefox driver windows side by side. I have successfully changed the size of the window using any of these methods:

```
    options = selenium.webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument("--width=200")
    options.add_argument("--height=200")
    driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

```
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(win_sizing.width, win_sizing.height)
```

However, I cannot manage to change the windows' positions:

```
# Has no effect on the window position
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
```

Are there arguments I can pass to the `FirefoxOptions`? I have tried with `--left=0`, `--top=0` and `--window-position=0,0` (all my guesses - Is there a command line reference somewhere?).

Javascript also has no effect:

```
driver.execute_script("window.moveTo(0,0);")
```

**How do I change the window position of the Firefox driver?**

Ubuntu 23.10, Gnome, Wayland. Python.

I'm starting to think that I have to fallback on X/Wayland/Gnome calls to reposition the window.

edit:
This seems to indicate that the driver is not in control of the window position at all :(  (Moving the window using the mouse still result in the same x and y coordinates)

```
>>> driver.set_window_rect(300, 300, 500, 500)
{'x': 26, 'y': 23, 'width': 500, 'height': 500}
```